Self-hosted V6 Swap API: Send quote request but no response
I used the jupiter-swap-api v6.0.15 version. The program ran for a long time, but the following command returned the Connection close response body.
curl -s 'http:127.0.0.1:8080/quote?inputMint=So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112&outputMint=EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v&amount=1000000&slippageBps=1'

The command is as follows:
RUST_LOG=info ./jupiter-swap-api --rpc-url http://127.0.0.1:8899 --snapshot-poll-interval-ms 30000 --allow-circular-arbitrage --expose-quote-and-simulate

The log is as follows:
[2024-04-29T07:18:39.732194Z INFO jupiter_swap_api] Found 96 logical cores, using 96 for the api
[2024-04-29T07:18:39.736664Z WARN jupiter_swap_api] Running in poll mode, this mode is not recommended
[2024-04-29T07:18:39.736681Z INFO jupiter_swap_api] Loading Jupiter router...
[2024-04-29T07:18:42.454958Z INFO jupiter_core::amms::loader] markets len(): 60781
[2024-04-29T07:18:42.932930Z WARN jupiter_core::amms::loader] Stakedex AMMs where not found in the cache, 137 out of 273
[2024-04-29T07:18:42.932946Z INFO jupiter_core::amms::loader] New dexes are disabled, [] are not loaded
[2024-04-29T07:18:42.933068Z INFO jupiter_core::amms::loader] updating amms with account_keys.len(): 63
[2024-04-29T07:18:43.436240Z INFO jupiter_core::amms::loader] Loaded 60727 amms from market cache
[2024-04-29T07:18:43.506626Z INFO jupiter_core::amms::loader] AMMS per label loaded: {"FluxBeam": 670, "Whirlpool": 1420, "Orca V2": 115, "Raydium": 55415, "Meteora": 1321, "Orca V1": 15, "Saber (Decimals)": 16, "Bonkswap": 15, "Oasis": 11, "Sanctum": 137, "OpenBook V2": 13, "Aldrin V2": 26, "Crema": 8, "Penguin": 11, "Mercurial": 13, "Invariant": 25, "GooseFX": 15, "Lifinity V2": 27, "Phoenix": 34, "Aldrin": 16, "Raydium CLMM": 317, "Cropper": 24, "Dexlab": 77, "Openbook": 44, "Saber": 68, "Saros": 26, "Meteora DLMM": 807, "Marinade": 1, "Token Swap": 31, "StepN": 3, "Perps": 1, "Lifinity V1": 3, "Helium Network": 2}
[2024-04-29T07:18:43.700314Z INFO jupiter_core::address_lookup_table_cache] Loading AddressLookupTableCache...
[2024-04-29T07:18:43.703747Z INFO jupiter_core::address_lookup_table_cache] Fetching 8091 address lookup tables
[2024-04-29T07:18:44.910403Z INFO jupiter_core::address_lookup_table_cache] Update 8091 ALTs into the AddressLookupTableCache in 1.206743081s
[2024-04-29T07:18:44.910429Z INFO jupiter_core::router] 60727 amms for 60727 lookup tables
[2024-04-29T07:18:46.086482Z INFO jupiter_core::router] Fetched 56491 mints
[2024-04-29T07:18:46.154236Z INFO jupiter_core::router] Perform initial update #1
[2024-04-29T07:18:46.166475Z INFO jupiter_core::router] create key_set: 12.22ms
[2024-04-29T07:18:56.838186Z INFO jupiter_core::router] getMA + insert 10.67s
[2024-04-29T07:18:57.169907Z INFO jupiter_core::router] update: 331.70ms
[2024-04-29T07:18:57.169928Z INFO jupiter_core::router] Perform initial update #2
[2024-04-29T07:18:57.180019Z INFO jupiter_core::router] create key_set: 10.09ms
[2024-04-29T07:18:58.275688Z INFO jupiter_core::router] getMA + insert 1.10s
[2024-04-29T07:18:58.389727Z INFO jupiter_core::router] update: 114.01ms
[2024-04-29T07:18:58.389746Z INFO jupiter_core::router] Perform initial update #3
[2024-04-29T07:18:58.398654Z INFO jupiter_core::router] create key_set: 8.91ms
[2024-04-29T07:18:58.681748Z INFO jupiter_core::router] getMA + insert 283.08ms
[2024-04-29T07:18:58.693039Z INFO jupiter_core::router] update: 11.26ms
[2024-04-29T07:18:59.397135Z INFO jupiter_core::price_tracker] Price tracker updated 56389 prices in 704.078067ms
[2024-04-29T07:18:59.465055Z INFO jupiter_swap_api] Started jupiter swap api on 0.0.0.0:8080, in 19.728371847s
[2024-04-29T07:18:59.503859Z INFO jupiter_core::router] create key_set: 11.87ms
[2024-04-29T07:19:00.168750Z INFO jupiter_core::price_tracker] Price tracker updated 56389 prices in 676.767281ms
[2024-04-29T07:19:00.837011Z INFO jupiter_core::price_tracker] Price tracker updated 56389 prices in 668.234532ms
[2024-04-29T07:19:05.209441Z INFO jupiter_core::price_tracker] Price tracker updated 56389 prices in 716.541777ms
[2024-04-29T07:19:10.190842Z INFO jupiter_core::price_tracker] Price tracker updated 56389 prices in 697.153121ms
[2024-04-29T07:19:12.026003Z INFO jupiter_core::router] getMA + insert 12.52s
[2024-04-29T07:19:12.069901Z INFO jupiter_core::router] update: 43.88ms
[2024-04-29T07:19:14.995518Z INFO jupiter_core::price_tracker] Price tracker updated 56389 prices in 502.528426ms
[2024-04-29T07:19:19.959001Z INFO jupiter_core::price_tracker] Price tracker updated 56389 prices in 465.285308ms
[2024-04-29T07:19:24.940892Z INFO jupiter_core::price_tracker] Price tracker updated 56389 prices in 447.210966ms
....

